# Navigation Architecture Component - Activities

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I've been following the docs from [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) to understand how this new navigation system works.

To go/back from one screen to another you need a component which implements `NavHost` interface.

> The NavHost is an empty view whereupon destinations are swapped in and
>   out as a user navigates through your app.

But, it seems that currently only Fragments implement `NavHost`

> The Navigation Architecture Component’s default NavHost implementation is NavHostFragment.

So, my questions are:

- Even if I have a very simple screen which can be implemented with an `Activity`, in order to work with this new navigation system, a `Fragment` needs to be hosted containing the actual view?
- Will `Activity` implement `NavHost` interface in a near future?

**--UPDATED--**

Based on ianhanniballake's answer, I understand that every activity contains its own navigation graph. But if I want to go from one activity to another using the nav component (replacing "old" `startActivity` call), I can use `activity destinations`. What is `activity destinations` is not clear to me because the [docs for migration](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-migrate) don't go into any detail:

> Separate Activities can then be linked by adding activity destinations to the navigation graph, replacing existing usages of startActivity() throughout the code base.

- Is there any benefit on using `ActivityNavigator` instead of `startActivity`?
- What is the proper way to go from activities when using the nav component?

Comment: Google now recommand using one activity per app, so i'm not sure they will impement NavHost from Activity

Comment: Yes I know but most apps out there are implemented using multiple activities. So it takes time to move from one implementation to another completely. So setting that bridge could help with the transition.

Comment: Coming to this question in 2023. If we have multi module app, usage of Navigation component isn't that briliant with Activity transitions (can't move from it beucase there is tons of logic) + isn't a god Activities an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to navigate from one activity to another without hosting a Fragment by using `ActivityNavigator`.

```
ActivityNavigator(this)
                    .createDestination()
                    .setIntent(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
                    .navigate(null, null)
```

Comment: seems navigate is not available now, do u got any replacement !

Comment: how is it better than `startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));` ?

Comment: This is great, In my case is assume that SecondActivity is a nav host and is it possible to navigate to the fragment inside the SecondActivity?

Comment: You can use  `ActivityNavigator(this).navigate(destination)` after creating destination with `val destination = ActivityNavigator(this).createDestination().setIntent(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))`

Answer (score 66):

The navigation graph only exists within a single activity. As per the [Migrate to Navigation guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-migrate), `<activity>` destinations can be used to start an Activity from within the navigation graph, but once that second activity is started, it is totally separate from the original navigation graph (it could have its own graph or just be a simple activity).

You can add an Activity destination to your navigation graph via the visual editor (by hitting the + button and then selecting an activity in your project) or by manually adding the XML:

```
<activity
    android:id="@+id/secondActivity"
    android:name="com.example.SecondActivity" />
```

Then, you can navigate to that activity (i.e., start the activity) by using it just like any other destination:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.secondActivity);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated the initial question with two follow up questions. I would really appreciate if you answer them.

Comment: You shouldn't be using ActivityNavigator itself, but just working with a `NavController`.

Comment: That was my first attempt and it didn't work: `{view} does not have a NavController set`. Be aware that that "view" reference contains only a `ConstraintLayout`. It seems that in order to work the view has to contain a Fragment, right? So if I don't want to instantiate a Fragment inside the Activity, the only way to navigate between graphs is using `ActivityNavigator `. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you're not using any NavHost at all even in your first activity, then you're never going to actually get 90% of the benefit out of Navigation and should probably just continue to do what you are already doing.

Comment: As far as I know the only component that implements NavHost is a Fragment, so, I understand that if I'm using Activities without Fragments (in response to "to do what you are already doing") I should keep using startActivity. Thanks for the support.

Comment: how to find navController from destination activity?

Comment: @SouravBagchi - a NavController only exists within a single Activity, so there's no access to a different Activity's NavController.

Comment: @ianhanniballake is there an "official" way to finish the current activity? e.g. MainActivity -> LoginActivity (has its own flow etc.) after doing the flow I want to close the activity (pop it) I've tried to use a "finish_flow" action with `app:popUpTo="NOT_SURE_WT_SHLD_GO_HERE" app:popUpToInclusive="true"` but with no success, also I really need this sep. activity as I don't want global nav ui elements during this flow.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Please shed some light on how to finish() the source activity after navigating to a new activity destination from the navhost in source activity. Facing similar issues which Joaquim Ley mentioned.

Comment: @HariKiran - `requireActivity().finish()`, same as always. Navigation is never going to finish your activity for you.

Comment: so, how to send data back from the first Activity to the Fragment of the first Activity? @ianhanniballake

Comment: @mantc_sdr - the guide for [Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) explains how to return a result from the SecondActivity to a fragment in the FirstActivity.

Answer (score 5):

I also managed to navigate from one activity to another without hosting a Fragment by using ActivityNavigator.

Kotlin:

```
val activityNavigator = ActivityNavigator( context!!)
                activityNavigator.navigate(
                    activityNavigator.createDestination().setIntent(
                        Intent(
                            context!!,
                            SecondActivity::class.java
                        )
                    ), null, null, null
                )
```

Java:

```
ActivityNavigator activityNavigator = new ActivityNavigator(this);
activityNavigator.navigate(activityNavigator.createDestination().setIntent(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)), null, null, null);
```

nav_graph.xml

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.codingwithmitch.navigationcomponentsexample.SampleFragment"
        android:label="fragment_sample"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sample">

    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_confirmationFragment_to_secondActivity"
            app:destination="@id/secondActivity" />

</fragment>
<activity
        android:id="@+id/secondActivity"
        android:name="com.codingwithmitch.navigationcomponentsexample.SecondActivity"
        android:label="activity_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_second" />
```

Kotlin:

```
lateinit var navController: NavController
navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_confirmationFragment_to_secondActivity)
```

Comment: I get an error in NavGraph: **no current navigation node**