# Android jetpack navigation: navigate from activity(splashscreen) to activity

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm developing an app still in its early stages. I'm learning jetpack navigation as it goes.

In short, I need to create a splashscreen, it would do its stuff (initializing etc..) then navigate to the registration/login flow(not implemented yet) or to the main flow (which uses a `BottomNavigationView`). So I though the easiest way would be to create a `SplashscreenActivity` and then navigate to `MainActivity`.

Only I can't figure out how to navigate from `SplashscreenActivity` to `MainActivity`, because `findNavController()` which I usually use in fragments, for activities requieres the id of the `navController` which I don't think it makes much sense in this case. Is it even possible to achieve that using the jetpack navigation?

Of course, I think I can always go for the good old `startActivity()`, but is that the right way to go?
Would I just be better with creating a `SplashscreenFragment` and handle everything in `MainActivity`?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031383/android-navigation-component-change-root-fragment/61031774#61031774

Comment: @MohammedAlaa not really, before disregarding the "activity" approach, I would like to know if it's possible to use it.

Comment: yes I think it's possible, but if you are using navigation component they recommend using single activity multiple fragments

Comment: if you will go with activity approach  check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452359/navigation-architecture-component-activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the navigation component allow to do this, but it's not really designed for.

So one can either switch to a one-activity architecture or do this:

```
ActivityNavigator(this)
                    .createDestination()
                    .setIntent(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
                    .navigate(null, null)
```

but digging in what this snippet does, reveal that it's equivalent to `startActivity()`, so it has no real use.